# Javascript: caretPositionFromPoint/caretRangeFromPoint is returning wrong range for Chinese characters at the beginning of line

Tags: javascript, html, caret

The `caretPositionFromPoint`/`caretRangeFromPoint` is returning the end of the line above it instead of the beginning of line(first character position) when clicking the first character of any line except the first line of paragraph.

**Steps to reproduce:**

Click the first character of any line except the first line of paragraph, it will return false because its returning wrong position.

For some freaking reason cannot create a runnable snippet of the code here on SO so please see the JsFiddle below.

**https://jsfiddle.net/zvt8wyxa/**

Any workaround will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I think I remember seeing a specs discussion about this, but I haven't time to dig this back. IIRC this is not a browser bug, but really a specs oddity. Not sure there is a workaround either... And regarding the "freaking reasons", I think it's because SO faced a huge number of spams written in Chinese at some time, and they kind of banned it in posts...